# Passing values to RESTful web service post method

Tags: java, xml, rest, xml-parsing, jax-rs

I am successfully created restful web service and deploy it in Apache Tomcat 7.0. After successful deployment I start my server. By using the below command i invoke the web service.

```
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/rest/samp/create");
```

My web method is

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public final String sample(final String xmlMessage) {

    return "<xml version=1.0><welcome>"+xmlmessage+"</welcome>";    
}
```

Here I am passing XML content as argument and get the XML content as response.

Now what I need is how to pass the XML content to the web method.

Comment: Where is "the web method" in your code?

Comment: I am really puzzled why this question got voted down twice. What is wrong with this question? To me, it is a truly legitimate question. If you find the English bothersome, just correct it, not vote it down. You can't presume that only people with perfect English are allowed to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the library in use here is Jersey.

You have to use a builder to set the appropriate HTTP headers, method and entity body.

```
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/rest/samp/create");
String request = "<your_xml>...</your_xml>";
String response = resource.accept(
     MediaType.TEXT_XML).
     header("X-FOO", "BAR"). //this line is not necessary, just an example
     type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).
     post(String.class, request);
```

But I recommend using JAXB instead. Creating XML as plain strings is just crude and unnecessarily annoying. It doesn't show in such a simple example (grabbing a whole XML and wrapping it with another tag) but it will soon enough.

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Curl :

```
http://curl.haxx.se/
```

simple command line to send data with post :

```
curl -d "here puts data" -X POST http://mysite/create
```